# Grails <g:if> in <g:select>

Tags: grails, select, gsp

I have this `<g:select>` in a `.gsp` file. But unlike any ordinary `<g:select>`'s this one would have the attribute `disabled=""` if a certain condition is met.

Following the code:

```
<g:select name="test" 
          from="${["foo1","foo2"]}" 
          <g:if test="${true}">disabled=""</g:if> />
```

It returned an error: `Grails tag [g:select] was not closed`

But when I change it into this:

```
<g:select name="test" 
          from="${["mu1","mu2","mu3"]}" 
          ${ if(true) { println "disabled=\"\"" } }/>
```

It returned this error: `Attribute value must be quoted.`

Both of the error message are under the exception, `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException`

The question is how could we make this work? Is there a possible answer without using a custom TagLib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GSP form field tags treat `disabled` as a boolean property, so you can say

```
<g:select .... disabled="${true}" />
```

Generally you should be able to use any expression under the usual Groovy-truth rules but I believe it makes a special case for the strings "true" and "false" (the latter would normally be considered `true` under Groovy-truth rules as a non-empty string). If in doubt you can always say

```
disabled="${(someExpression) as boolean}"
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use the println, try this

```
<g:select .... ${(conditional)?"disabled":""} ... />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <g:select disabled="${true}"...
```

is fine but when you submit and it is a required field the value will not be submitted so use this jQuery code to enable the field when pressing the submit button

```
    $(function() {

        $('form').on('submit', function() {
            $(this).find(':disabled').removeAttr('disabled');
        });

    });
```