# conditions inside g:select gsp tag

Tags: grails, gsp

I am using g:select and wishes to put a default selected value. However when default value is null it should display a 'Please select one'. However, I cannot seem to work it out.

Code is below:

This is the Address object - options contained in a drop down

```
Address
    Long id
    String name
    Sheriff sheriff
    String phaseCode
```

ListOfSheriffs is a list of sheriffs-contains list of Sheriff object

```
Sheriff
    Long id
    String name
    //other property here
```

defaultSheriff is the default sheriff of an Address

The below code is one on my gsp

```
<g:select optionKey = "id" 
          optionValue = "${{sheriff.name +' '+sheriff.id}}"  
          name="sheriff.name"
          from="${ListOfSheriffs}"
          value="${(defaultSheriff == null) ? 'Please select one' : defaultSheriff}" />
```

However, wether defaultSheriff is null 'Please select one' wont display, the page only displays the first sheriff from the ListOfSheriffs.

I got this solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12507918/grails-gif-in-gselect)
. And not so sure what I left out.

Also, I tried using noSelection based on what I've read on [docs](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/1.3.6/ref/Tags/select.html). However, the result is, the default selected value on dropdown list on the page is always 'Please select one' even though the defaultSheriff is not null

```
<g:select optionKey = "id" 
          optionValue = "${{sheriff.name +' '+sheriff.id}}"  
          name="sheriff.name"
          from="${ListOfSheriffs}"
          value="${defaultSheriff}"
          noSelection="[null:'Please select one']" />
```

If something is not clear with what I have provided, feel free to point it add, I'll be happy to detail it. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that you need smth like this

```
<g:select optionKey = "id" 
          optionValue = "${{it.name +' '+ it.id}}"  
          name="sheriff.name"
          from="${ListOfSheriffs}"
          value="${sheriff?.id ?: defaultSheriff?.id}"
          noSelection="['':'Please select one']" />
```